# Bitmap while assigning height width crashes

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim objBmpImage AS Bitmap = New Bitmap(9450, 6750)
```

On execution of above line of code application crashes - Argument Exception- Parameter is not valid.

Please advice.

Comment: Does this even  compile for you, **objBmpImage** is not even intialised

Comment: Please check the question now. It was printed by mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this bitmap requires a huge contiguous unmanaged memory to store the bitmap bits.
More than what is available for your process. So its one way of saying the size you want is not supported. Try reducing and it would work.

Comment: Probably true. The image is 63,787,500 pixels in area. At 32 bits per pixel that's 2,041,200,000 bits (255,150,000 bytes)

Comment: Presently the RAM is 2 GB. Is it correct hardware to execute this code ?

Comment: It is working fine at 9000 * 6000. After this it starts to crash

Comment: I increased the RAM to 3 GB still same issue

Comment: This is not the answer to my requested question. I tried executing the same line on another machine with same machine configuration and it's worked. But still not getting why crashing on my machine. So obviously this is not a memory issue.

Comment: its dependent on the memory available for the process, it less in case of your machine and not in the other case (coz it wasn't even happening on my machine which is 2GB)

Comment: No, Both the machines have only Visual studio opened.

Comment: Yes agreed only VS opened, but how much memory is **available**. Its got to be different in both these machines else why would it work when you reduced the dimensions.

Comment: It is occurring now in both machines.

Comment: I underwent an article saying that it's a GDI+ issue, In order to resolve it, the contiguous memory blocks should be available. I agree with your answer Thanks to you and ChrisF. I cannot vote as I have less number of points.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objBmpImage AS Bitmap = New Bitmap(objYourOriginBmpImage, New Size(9450, 6750))
```

You are using the name *objBmpImage* thrice and in the wrong context.

Comment: When i posted my answer the original code snippet was: Dim objBmpImage AS objBmpImage = New Bitmap(objBmpImage, New Size(9450, 6750))

Comment: Yes it was written by mistake

Comment: Are you sure that the ArgumentException is thrown by this line?

Comment: Yes, On more thing, I prepared the sample application it is working fine there but in the project same line is crashing

Answer (score 0):

U r using the same object in the bitmap constructor before its actually being created. Try passing an already existing bitmap to the constructor.

Comment: Please check the question now. It was printed by mistake

Comment: i think the size u r mentioning is very large. Keep some smaller size and try.

Comment: Actually, these are dynamic coordinates coming from database. So, We cannot change it.

Comment: Check for the max value the bitmap accepts and if the value from your database is larger than this, restrict the number to the max value.

Comment: No we cannot do that. Images will be created according to the coordinates coming from database.

Comment: Mine is a 32-bit machine and it runs fine with no exceptions!!

Comment: I underwent an article saying that it's a GDI+ issue, In order to resolve it, the contiguous memory blocks should be available.

Answer (score 0):

You're bitmap is too large to process (I think you will hit a 2GB limit).

Try processing it in smaller chunks and merging files together if necessary.