# c# Parameter is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

```
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(7016, 9921);
```

Part of the method:

```
public Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap b, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
```

nWidth and nHeight have thrown this same error, so I replaced it with explicit values and still the same error, it seems to work for smaller numbers though, but:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx

Doesn't seem to indicate there is any limit? I've tried:

```
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(7016, 9921);
Bitmap result = new Bitmap((int)7016, (int)9921);
```

All fail the same way.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap

Comment: The exception occurs due the available memory. Piotr has probably more memory.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801652/bitmap-while-assigning-height-width-crashes/5802113#5802113.. similar to what you have now

Comment: You do know you're trying to allocate about 280 megabytes, right?  Try smaller sizes to see if you can find a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is just not enough memory to allocate bitmap.

Comment: How much memory will I need?  Wouldn't that throw a different type of error?

Comment: ~265.5 MB. But note that it should be the continuous part of memory. Also you can change BPP value from 32 to 24 or 16 - it will require less memory.

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when you do not have the available memory to allocate such large of a block.

Admittedly, it's not a very good error message, and I'm not sure why Microsoft chose this error message rather than an OutOfMemory exception, but that's what happens.