# Working with large bitmaps causes Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, memory-management, gdi+

I need to edit(Increase the height) the Image on the fly.
The file is mostly 5000*4000 in dimension. I see the memory shoots up to peak level when I create a bmp of large dimensions and call Graphics.DrawImage method on the bmp instance.

How do I get rid of the Out Of Memory exception? Is there a way to work with large bitmaps in c# ?

Comment: Its a memory issue Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801652/bitmap-while-assigning-height-width-crashes/5802113#5802113

Comment: I guess you are having same problem as others have when you try to take more than a GB of memory for the .dll. The possible answer could be to Use a stream and process files in chunks.

Comment: An 80 megabyte bitmap is large but not humongous.  You however will run out of memory when you don't call Dispose() when you should.  The garbage collector doesn't run often enough to hide this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the Huge amount of Memory required for the operation. Yours is taking about some GigaBytes, so the solution could be to use a Stream and process the file in chunks.

Or the the best option would be to use some Third party library for it. Below are some for .Net

> [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)
>
> [Image Resizer](http://imageresizing.net/)

Also have a look at this SO question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on you application specific requeirements, it's not very clear from yuor post, but generaly, working with big media files (images, sounds, videos) I think really good solution is

[Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx)

Save yuor image on the disk in memory mapped file and resize it having on disk, by free yuor RAM as much as possible from a lot of data that you, probably, don't need  to have a fast access(in that moment at least)

Hope this helps. 
Regards.

Comment: this is not easy to do in .net

Comment: This is much easier then was before, believe me, as now you have wrapped .NET class. (only for .NET Framework 4.0)

Comment: OOM is *never* caused by running out of RAM.  Bitmaps already use an MMF, creating more just lets you run out of virtual memory quicker.

Comment: @Hans: "Bitmaps already use an MMF" are you sure about this ?

Comment: Yes.  One side-effect of it is easy to observe: the file is locked when you use the Bitmap(string) constructor.

Comment: Hm... but it doesn't mean that it uses Mapped file technique actually. I searched on internet before, and didn't find anything that confirms yuor opinion, but also nothing that negates it. Do you have some links on subject ?

Comment: I was curious about it too, so I decompiled `System.Drawing.Bitmap(string)` and could not see any MMF code... 

Do the following GDI method do it? `int num = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(filename, out zero);`