# i am getting this Exception "Parameter is not valid.at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, httphandler

**i made the image re size Handler. i am getting this Exception.**

> "HttpApplication.ExecuteStep =>
>   CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
>   => ImageHandler.ProcessRequest|System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.    at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32
>   height, PixelFormat format)    at
>   Holmgrens.ImageResize.IMGHandller.ImageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)".

**Here is my code.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace Xyz.ImageResize.IMGHandller
{
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        // incoming query string variables

        private string imagePath = string.Empty;        // path=    virtual path required

        private string imageWidth = "0";                // w=   0 means use original

        private string imageHeight = "0";               // h=

        private string imageQuality = "0";              // q=

        private string constrainProportions = "true";   // cp=  true or false

        private string rotation = "0";                  // r= rotation in degrees, optional, 0 is default.



        private const Int32 maxQuality = 100;

        private const Int32 minQuality = 30;

        private const string imageNotFound = "~/SlideData/TempImg/Desert.jpg";

        private string mimeType = "image/jpeg";

        //get imag config item
        //ImageConfiguration imgconsetting = new ImageConfiguration();





        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            try
            {

                // get query string parameters           

                imagePath = context.Request.QueryString["path"];

                imageWidth = context.Request.QueryString["w"];

                imageHeight = context.Request.QueryString["h"];

                imageQuality = context.Request.QueryString["q"];

                constrainProportions = context.Request.QueryString["cp"];

                rotation = context.Request.QueryString["r"];

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imagePath)))
                {

                    imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imagePath);

                }

                else
                {

                    // displays an empty image holder or make sure you have a not found image

                    imageQuality = "100";

                    imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imageNotFound);

                }

                //get file info

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(imagePath);
                if (fi.Extension.ToLower() == ".gif")
                    mimeType = "image/gif";
                else if (fi.Extension.ToLower() == ".png")
                    mimeType = "image/png";
                else
                    mimeType = "image/jpeg";

                // sets the HTTP MIME type of the output stream.

                // jpeg is default       

                context.Response.ContentType = mimeType;



                // clear all content output from the buffer stream

                context.Response.Clear();



                // response is cacheable by clients and shared (proxy) caches
                context.Response.Expires = 24 * 60; //one day;
                string ETag = Hash.GetHash(string.Format("{0}{1}", imagePath, fi.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString()), Hash.HashType.MD5);
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
                context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(fi.LastWriteTimeUtc);
                context.Response.Cache.SetETag(string.Format("\"{0}\"", ETag));




                // Buffer response so that page is sent

                // after processing is complete.

                context.Response.BufferOutput = true;





                //if image height is zero,calculate the image height with aspect ration of image
                if (imageHeight == "0")
                {
                    imageHeight = ImageHeightWithAspect(imagePath, Convert.ToInt16(imageWidth)).ToString();

                }



                Int32 originalWidth = 0;

                Int32 originalHeight = 0;

                Int32 newWidth = 0;

                Int32 newHeight = 0;

                Int64 quality = 0;



                // set the quality of the jpeg image returned.. 30 (low) - 100 (high)

                if (Int64.TryParse(imageQuality, out quality))
                {

                    if (quality > maxQuality) { quality = maxQuality; }

                    if (quality < minQuality) { quality = minQuality; }

                }

                else

                { quality = maxQuality; }



                // ENCODING

                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder encoder =

                  System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;



                System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter encoderParameter =

                    new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);



                // create an array with one parameter; quality

                System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters codecParams =

                    new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);

                codecParams.Param[0] = encoderParameter;



                // Gets the codecs for this image type (jpeg)

                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = getEncoderInfo();



                // Create a bitmap to hold new image, uses Bitmap.GetThumbnailImage

                using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapOriginal = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imagePath))
                {

                    originalWidth = bitmapOriginal.Width;

                    originalHeight = bitmapOriginal.Height;



                    Int32.TryParse(imageWidth, out newWidth);

                    Int32.TryParse(imageHeight, out newHeight);



                    if (newWidth > originalWidth) { newWidth = originalWidth; }

                    if (newHeight > originalHeight) { newHeight = originalHeight; }



                    // Constrain Proportions provides scaling by width

                    // False by default which forces width and height - when exact size required

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(constrainProportions)

                        && constrainProportions.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {

                        newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(imageWidth);

                        Double scaleFactor = 0.0;

                        // scale the image based on the width

                        if (originalWidth > originalHeight)
                        {

                            // landscape

                            Int32 largestDimension = (Math.Max(originalWidth, originalHeight));

                            scaleFactor = ((Double)newWidth / (Double)largestDimension);

                        }

                        else
                        {

                            // portrait

                            Int32 smallestDimension = (Math.Min(originalWidth, originalHeight));

                            scaleFactor = ((Double)newWidth / (Double)smallestDimension);

                        }

                        newHeight = Convert.ToInt32((originalHeight * scaleFactor));

                    }



                    // Create the new bitmap image

                    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                    {

                        // use the same resolution

                        bitmapNew.SetResolution(bitmapOriginal.HorizontalResolution, bitmapOriginal.VerticalResolution);



                        // Create the graphics object to draw the old bitmap on the new sized bitmap.

                        using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmapNew))
                        {

                            // resize using the highest possible quality for best results

                            graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;



                            graphic.DrawImage(bitmapOriginal,

                                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(-1, -1, newWidth + 1, newHeight + 1), // destination

                                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight), //source

                                System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel); //using pixels
                            graphic.Dispose();

                        }



                        // Rotate the bitmap

                        switch (Convert.ToInt32(rotation))
                        {

                            case 90:

                                bitmapNew.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

                                break;

                            case 180:

                                bitmapNew.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

                                break;

                            case 270:

                                bitmapNew.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);

                                break;

                            default:

                                // always show as original

                                bitmapNew.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);

                                break;

                        }



                        // context.Response.OutputStream enables binary output to the outgoing HTTP content body.

                        // codecInfo is the image type (jpeg)

                        // codecParams is the quality
                        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(bitmapNew);
                        bitmapNew.Dispose();
                        //bm.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, codecInfo, codecParams);                    
                        //bm.Dispose();
                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bm.Save(stream, codecInfo, codecParams);
                            stream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                            stream.Dispose();
                        }
                        bm.Dispose();

                    }
                    bitmapOriginal.Dispose();

                }
                encoderParameter.Dispose();
                codecParams.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                response.write(ex);

            }

        }



        /// <summary>

        /// Return the codec info for jpeg images

        /// </summary>

        /// <param name="mimeType"></param>

        /// <returns></returns>

        private System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo()
        {

            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;

            encoders = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();



            Int32 i = 0;

            while (i < encoders.Length)
            {

                if (encoders[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                {

                    return encoders[i];

                }

                i++;

            }



            return null;

        }



        public bool IsReusable

        { get { return true; } }


        private int ImageHeightWithAspect(string fileName,int newWidth)
        {

            Image original = Image.FromFile(fileName);

            //Find the aspect ratio between the height and width.

            float aspect = (float)original.Height / (float)original.Width;

            //Calculate the new height using the aspect ratio

            // and the desired new width.

            int newHeight = (int)(newWidth * aspect);            

            //Dispose of our objects.

            original.Dispose();
            return newHeight;



        }
    }
}
```

please guide me how to remove this exception.

thanks
Humayoo

Comment: What are the values for height and width, might be similar to [Bitmap parameter not valid - Argument exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801652/bitmap-while-assigning-height-width-crashes/5802113#5802113)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your newWidth or newHeight is incorrect in this line:

```
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
```

You need to debug your application to determine what the incorrect value is and how to fix it.