# C# Console Application won't work if started remotely via PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm quite desperate because my C# Application won't start if I open it remotely with the PowerShell.

My application is doing some hardware access and grabs a camera picture. If I open this .exe over the VS Remote Debugger it works fine. If I open it with TeamViewer directly on the remote client, it works well.

But if I try to open my application over the PowerShell, it crashes during a bitmap operation

```
Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(ROI[2] - ROI[0], ROI[3] - ROI[1], source.PixelFormat);
```

with the error "Parameter is not valid!".

The values that are beeing passed are:

```
new Bitmap(2544 - 1, 1944 - 3, Format24bppRgb)
```

Why is the exe behaving completely different even though the PS doesn't anything different than simply starting a new instance of the application?

Here is how I open the executable:

```
PS Z:\> invoke-command -ScriptBlock { & 'C:\Users\###\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\###\Commo
n\Remote Console\bin\Debug\Remote Console.exe' -save_path=C:\Temp\Images fov=large filename=test1 setposition=200.00 Ope
ration=getpicture } -Session $remotesession
```

Here's stack trace:

Sure (sorry for having forgotten):

> Parameter is not valid. System.Drawing    at
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat
>   format)    at Utility.ImageProcessing.CopyBitmap(Bitmap source,
>   Int32[] ROI) in C:\Users###\Documents\Visual Studio 2015
>   \Projects###\Common\Utility\Utility.cs:line 46    at
>   Utility.###ServiceUtilities.ByteToImage(Int32 width, Int32 height,
>   Byte[] imageData) in C:\Users###\Doc uments\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects###Interface\Common\Utility###ServiceUtilities.cs:line
>   232    at Utility.###ServiceUtilities.getImage(ImageServerClient
>   client, cameraSelect Cam, FieldType FT, Int32 WaitTime)  in
>   C:\Users###\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects###Interface\Common\Utility###ServiceUtilities.cs: line
>   61

What the heck is going on?! ~.~

**UPDATE:** I found sth interesting. Any creation of a new bitmap will fail if its bigger than a defined size around 500*500*24bpp. May this be caused by some memory overflow? On the remote PC is still enough ram free (5,7Gb)!

Comment: Can we see stack trace of exception?

Comment: Sure (sorry for having forgotten):

Comment: in your PS command it's Commo n  and in stack trace it common  (in path)

Comment: amit you're right. I don't know why but the PS does still not support a millenium version of copy&paste. It's still stuck in the 80s... Actually there's no whitespace.

Comment: Are you sure about `ROI` values? Can you print them before calling `Bitmap` constructor?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure. It's the values I posted and are direclty printed after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible your image is not getting loaded into the memory in the given time. Try to use thread.Sleep for few seconds while your image gets loaded. That might be the issue using powershell and was getting having sufficient time when accessing using VS remotedebugger.

Also for checking. Log the Date time  in millisecond before you load image and after you load image (Using remote debugger  and powershell both). In case of powershell if error occurs check the time when error occurs. That way you would know how much time does it takes to load image

Comment: I tried
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(ROI[2] - ROI[0], ROI[3] - ROI[1], source.PixelFormat);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

but it didn't change anything. The error raises when trying to create a new bitmap. Secound sleep will never be reached.

Comment: are you disposing your bitmap when no longer in use? This error also occurs when Memoryoutofexception occurs. and is your code was build in x86 platform ?

Comment: The project files are built to Any CPU and are executed on both x64 computer. The Bitmap is beeing disposed if no exception will break up code execution before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419778/system-drawing-bitmapint32-int32-parameter-not-valid-in-wpf-but-not-win-forms this might help you.